# c ++ Leer archivo con acentos

Tags: c++, txt, fstream

Buen dia, estoy en un pequeño proyecto donde necesito leer archivos .txt, el problema es que algunos estan en ingles y otros en español, se esta presentando el caso en que alguna informacion viene con acento y debo mostrarla en la consola con el acento.

No tengo problemas para mostrar acentos en la consola con setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "C");

mi problema es al leer el archivo .txt en la lectura no detecta los acentos y lee caracteres raros.

mi código de práctica es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using std::cout;

int main(){
    
    

    std::ifstream archivo;
    std::string texto;
    
    archivo.open("entradaDisciplinas.txt");
    
    if (archivo.fail()){
        
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo. \n";
        
        exit(1); // finaliza la funcion.
        
    }
    setlocale (LC_CTYPE, "");
    while(getline(archivo,texto)){ // Mientras no sea el final del archivo.
        
        std::cout<<texto<<"\n";
        
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

El archivo .txt en cuestión contiene:

```
Inicio
D1
Biatlón
S1
255
E1
Esprint 7,5 km (M); 100; 200
E2
Persecucion 10 km (M); 100; 200
ff
```

obviamente estoy teniendo problemas con 'ó' pero de igual manera tengo otros .txt con otros caracteres con acentos por lo que necesito una solución para todos estos caracteres.

Investigando, he leído e intentado implementar wstring y wifstream, pero no he podido implementar eso con éxito.

Estoy tratando de lograr esto en Windows, de la misma manera que necesito que la solución funcione en Linux, en este momento estoy usando dev c ++ 5.11

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.